# What is the mechanism principle of the grid fins in F9?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, design, engine-design, engines

What is the mechanism principle of the grid fins in F9?
or how to design the mechanism for the electricity grid fins?
or how to design a electricity folding wing like the grid fins in F9?

Comment: So you want to know about how the grid fins are designed, instead of what their function is?

Comment: What do you mean by 'electricity grid fins'? That makes no sense.

Comment: Voted to reopen, the modified question is no longer a duplicate.

Comment: Not voting to reopen. The question is still very unclear. *mechanism principle*? *electricity grid fins*? *electricity folding wing*? Probably a language barrier, but that has to be resolved first.